# tfs 2012 build service and 2012 build controller

Tags: build, tfs, controller, upgrade, agent

I am currently troubleshooting an issue where we have upgraded the tfs main server (which also has the build controller on it) to 2012 update 2. However, the build, running under tfs 2010 build service, will not run. In Microsoft documentation is says you can run 2010 build service with 2010 build controller. However, can you run a 2010 build service against a 2012 controller.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it is not possible to use a 2010 Build Agent with a 2012 Build Controller, but it is possible to use 2010 Build Agent/Controller with TFS 2012: http://nakedalm.com/visual-studio-2012-update-2-supports-2010-build-servers/
If you have the option you could install a Build Controlle on the machine where the agent is running.

Comment: Thanks. I did see that article, but I don't see anything that says  you can't do this. Our clients were hoping that the 2010 builds would just work, but it seems that having the build service on the 2012 main server has thrown a wrench in their plans.

Comment: I can't find an article that says that Controller and Agent need to have the same version, but I'm pretty sure about that. Can you configure the 2010 Build Agent on your 2012 Build Controller? If yes, what error messages do you get during the build. If it is not possible, that you should install 2010 Controller on the Build Agent and connect that Controller to your TFS.